# How to update Selenium JAVA test results in Azure DevOps?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, selenium-java

I am working with azure devops, and using Java selenium to runs test scripts, I couldn't find a way to post my results in the test plan whether it fails or passed with screenshots.
I already have a report generated with screenshots in the pipeline, but I want it to be updated in the test plan in each relevant manual test case.

I searched and found some workarounds, first is to migrate the project and use visual basic C# as it already can be integrated with azure devops but this will be impossible to do in this project,
Or connect my script using APIs to update the results, this seems to be more logical solution but don't know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium testing is automated testing, it doesn't make sense to upload the Selenium test results to manual test cases.

To run test as part of a test plan in Azure DevOps we can [Associate automated tests with test cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops). But Java Selenium is not supported here. See [What types of tests are supported?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops#q-what-types-of-tests-are-supported). So, if you want to associate Selenium automated tests with test cases in test plan, you can try to migrate the project and use visual basic `C#` as you already mentioned.

BTW, there's already a suggestion ticket raised to request the feature to support Java Selenium [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-execute-automated-tests-via-test-plan-for-n/1144675), you can vote to make it happen in the future.

If you still just want to update a manual test result with an attachment, then you can try to call the following REST APIs to update your manual test result:

- [Attachments - Create Test Run Attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/create-test-run-attachment?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)
- [Attachments - Create Test Result Attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/create-test-result-attachment?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

More information please reference the following docs and blogs:

- [UI test with Selenium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops)
- [Automating Selenium Tests in Azure Pipelines](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/selenium/)
- [Selenium – Java & Azure DevOps](https://learndevtestops.com/2021/01/17/selenium-java-azure-devops-lets-unleash-the-power/)

Comment: @AhmedAlaaEwis May I know any update? Is the answer helpful?